# Поиск комбинации символов в строке

Tags: c, алгоритм

Есть строка, например "Простой пример строки для проверки работы алгоритма, опрос."

Есть вот такая комбинация "про"

На выходе нужно получить следующие слова: "Простой проверки опрос" 
Часть алгоритма нужно сделать рекурсивным.

Как я понимаю - нужно вначале разбить строку на слова, заменив пробелы '\0'.
Нужно как-то получить указатели на слова - но тут у меня возникла заминка.

Дальше нужно создать массив возможных вариантов комбинации, т.е. "про рпо опр орп роп пор".

И в конце сравнивать каждое слово с массива комбинаций посимвольно с строкой, но это не очень эфективно.

Comment: А "проверки" не нужно? Почему? Какое общее правило, что нужно вытащить?

Comment: нужно получить слова в которых есть данная комбинация.

Comment: Тогда почему "проверки" не выбрано? И - нужно в любых вариантах? Скажем, "опрос" - из-за "опр" или из-за "про"? А что насчет "апарао"?

Comment: Забыл дописать. Нет, нужно только в тех вариантах где данные буквы стоят вместе т.е. "опрос" из-за "опр". "апарао" не нужно.

Comment: А "орпос" подойдёт?

Comment: Да, "орпос" подойдет.

Comment: Куда рекурсию воткнуть решайте сами, возможно как раз для перестановок `"опр"`. Но всё и без неё решается (см. дополннение к ответу).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот болванка. Рекурсивно тут можно гонять `set` по `word` (или наоборот):

```
#include <string.h>
static const char DELIMITERS[] = " \n\r\t";

static size_t find_set( const char *src, const char *set )
{
    size_t words = 0;
    char *dup = strdup( src );

    if( dup ) {
        char *word = strtok( dup, DELIMITERS );
        while( word ) {
            /*
             * а здесь проверяем есть ли в word искомое,
             * есть - printf( "%zu. %s\n", ++words, word );
             */
            word = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS );
        }
        free( dup );
    }   
    return words;
}
```

---

Правда, зачем тут рекурсия - непонятно, всё и без неё можно сделать:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const char DELIMITERS[] = " \n\r\t";

static size_t find_set( const char *src, const char *set )
{
    size_t words = 0;
    char *dup = strdup( src );

    if( dup ) {
        /* set_length введена для наглядности, см. ниже */
        size_t set_length = strlen( set );
        char *word = strtok( dup, DELIMITERS );

        while( word ) {
            if( strspn( set, word ) >= set_length ) {
            /* 
             * эту проверку можно упростить до:
             * if( !set[strspn( set, word )] ) {
             */
                printf( "%zu. %s\n", ++words, word );
            }
            word = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS );
        }
        free( dup );
    }
    return words;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char src[] =
        "prostoj primer stroki dlja proverki raboty algoritma, opros.";
    find_set( src, "rpo" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TS нечётко определил в постановке задачи понятие "комбинация". Если имеется в виду ЛЮБАЯ комбинация заданных символов, то надо использовать strspn, а если порядок символов именно такой, как указан, то надо использовать strstr.

Comment: @Sergey, кроме вопроса есть ещё комментарии к нему, там всё сказано.

Comment: @Sergey `strspn(, "oo")` что выдаст на строку `cooler`?

Comment: Смотрим man: "The  strspn() function returns the number of bytes in the initial segment of s which consist only of bytes from accept.". Следовательно: 0. А вот вызов функции strcspn выдаст именно то, что нужно: 1.